# Express not saving after req.user.save()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

In the following code, the user isn't getting saved.

```
router.patch('/onboard', auth.requireLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
  if (req.user.settings.onboarding[req.body.page]) {
    res.status(409).json({
      status: 'Error: Trying to onboard for a page that has already been onboarded.',
    });
  }

  console.log(req.body.page);
  req.user.settings.onboarding[req.body.page] = true;
  console.log(req.user.settings.onboarding);
  req.user
    .save()
    .then(function (res) {
      console.log(res);
      res.status(200).json({
        status: 'Successful',
      });
    })
    .catch(function () {
      res.status(500).json({
        status: 'Internal server error.',
      });
    })
  ;
});
```

`req.user.settings.onboarding.equityCalculator` starts off as `false` and I want to set it as `true`. All of the console logs indicate that this is happening. However, when I check my database, it isn't updated.

By "check my database" I mean "look in Robo 3T". But I also mean querying the database and looking at the user I get back.

Furthermore, the following code works perfectly. I don't see how this code works but the code above does not work.

```
router.patch('/subscribe-to-email', auth.requireLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
  if (req.user.emailOptIn) {
    res.status(409).json({
      status: 'You can\'t subscribe if you are already currently subscribed.',
    });
  }

  req.user.emailOptIn = true;
  req.user
    .save()
    .then(function () {
      res.status(200).json({
        status: 'Successful',
      });
    })
    .catch(function () {
      res.status(500).json({
        status: 'Internal server error.',
      });
    })
  ;
});
```

Here is the relevant part of my User schema:

```
UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  emailOptIn: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
    required: true,
  },
  settings: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
    required: true,
    default: defaultSettings,
  },
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, it worked for me in a similar situation:

```
req.user.settings.onboarding[req.body.page] = true;
req.user.markModified('settings.onboarding');
req.user.save()
```

The lack of saving seems to occur when setting array indices, like in your example. Marking the modified array allows the saving to occur properly.

Comment: Ah, that did the trick, thanks! FWIW it's because it is a Mixed type in this case, not because of setting an array index - https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed.